# How to convert UFT test case to TOSCA

Tags: automation, qtp, tosca

I am trying to convert UFT test case to TOSCA.
I have found TCMigration API and The connector project, in Github . In the "How to Use" Manual, below step is mentioned.
**Reference the downloaded TCMigrationAPI assembly into FrameworkMigratorConnector project.**

ANyone who has worked on UFT to TOSCA conversion, please help with this. thanks in advance.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Not yet.!! any update with you??@ sailaja.p

Comment: No update.. still trying

Comment: Have to place both the dll files in C>Program files>tricentis>commander and you will be able to see the options to import.under project root folder in Tosca

Comment: not able to import

Comment: The latest version of DLL works with 13.2 and above only